# cannot find -lboost_filesystem and -lboost_system

Tags: c++, boost, g++

I am using boost::filesystem in my sample program, but getting linking error.

Here is the sample program:

```
#include<boost/filesystem.hpp>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string fromPath = "/home/anurag/testfile";
    string toPath = "/home/anurag/testfile";

    boost::filesystem::copy_file(fromPath,toPath);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the steps in an attempt to fix this issue:

**1.** `g++ -g test.cpp -o out -I/apps/rcast/anurag/vendor/RH6.1AS_64/x86_64/boost_1_64_0/`    **Note**: inside this `boost` and `lib` directories present,and the `filesystem.hpp` is in `boost/`

I got linking errors here because i had missed to include `lboost_system` and `lboost_filesystem`

**2.** Specified -L option and specified the libraries during build :

`g++ -g test.cpp -o out -I/apps/rcast/anurag/vendor/RH6.1AS_64/x86_64/boost_1_64_0/ -L/apps/rcast/anurag/vendor/RH6.1AS_64/x86_64/boost_1_64_0/lib/ -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem`

Error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_filesystem
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_system
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

**3.** added library path in LD_LIBRARY_PATH even though not required as i specified in -L option
Now `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` shows `/xenv/gcc_gnu/X/6.1.0/lib64:/apps/rcast/anurag/vecndor/RH6.1AS_64/x86_64/boost_1_64_0/lib`

Still same Error.

In `boost_1_64_0/lib/` libs present are `ls -lart libboost*system*` :

```
libboost_filesystem-gcc61-mt-sd-1_64.a
libboost_system-gcc61-mt-sd-1_64.a
libboost_filesystem-gcc61-mt-s-1_64.a
libboost_system-gcc61-mt-s-1_64.a
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-lboost_filesystem` causes the linker to look for a file named `libboost_filesystem.a` or `libboost_filesystem.so` as your file is called `libboost_filesystem-gcc61-mt-s-1_64.a` you need to pass `-lboost_filesystem-gcc61-mt-s-1_64` to the linker

Comment: Since the boost documentation won't mention which header/function is under which lib, what is the best way to know which library should be used for linking while building the code?

Comment: The documentation is organised by library?

Comment: copy_file is part of filesystem library. The libraries by index are found here. https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_34_1/libs/libraries.htm But for this to work lboost_system is needed too which is not found in the list. How can i know that lboost_system is required too

Comment: @anurag86 From my experience, there is no simple way to know that another boost library must be linked even though the corresponding header is not explicitly included. But if you use cmake, there is no need to add `-lboost_system` in this case. CMake will figure out that `-lboost_system` is required to compile a file that includes `boost/filesystem`.

Comment: The simplest approach if not using some dependency manager is probably to try building then Google the missing symbol in the error message to find which library you need

Answer (score 2):

Finding the correct linker options for the boost libraries can be painful. I suggest leaving it to `cmake` to sort out these details. With this **CMakeLists.txt** file your code can be compiled:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project (copyfile LANGUAGES CXX)
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS filesystem)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} test)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} Boost::filesystem)
```

The `cmake`-assisted compilation can be done with the usual procedure:

1. add the `CMakeLists.txt` file to the directory containing your source code
2. `mkdir build && cd build`
3. `cmake ..` and `make`

---

Note that there is a typo/bug in your code:
The copy instruction should be

```
boost::filesystem::copy_file(fromPath,toPath);
       ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Note that you'll probably need to provide cmake with a hint to the boost location as it's not on a system path